# Macro containing a returning function

Tags: c, function, macros

I need to combine the two below functions(the second takes as an arguement
 the return value of the first one) into one macro.

```
#define SetDSTimeHours(a,b)

uint8_t FormatDSMode(char data,char mode);
void SetDSData(char address,char data);
```

The functions work as intended on their own but i can't find a way to put
 them in one macro.
 So, basically what i need is a macro like this that it works:

```
#define SetDSTimeHours(a,b) {\uint8_t (c)=FormatDSMode(a,b);\SetDSData(0x02,(c));\}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does away with the intermediate variable:

```
#define SetDSTimeHours(a_, b_) SetDSData(0x02,(char)(FormatDSMode((a_),(b_))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, to make a macro work properly, put it in a do while false loop: it lets you use it with if statements without giving you syntax errors.

Replace the curly braces with `do {` and `} while (false)`, respectively.

Considering that `uint8_t c` is only used for the function call `SetDSData`, change the macro to use FormatDSMode as a parameter to SetDSData.

Your code should become:

```
#define SetDSTimeHours(a, b) do { SetDSData(0x02, FormatDSMode(a, b)) } while (false)
```

Of course, you don't need to surround a single statement with do while (false), so you could just write:

```
#define SetDSTimeHours(a, b) SetDSData(0x02, FormatDSMode(a, b))
```

This is only a workaround for this instance; it won't always work. Macros are evil, and should generally be replaced with inline functions. A better example would be:

```
inline void SetDSTimeHours(char a, const char b) {
    uint8_t c = FormatDSMode(a, b);
    SetDSData(0x02, c);
}
```

Using inline functions allows you to declare variables without much hassle.